# HTTParty Digest Auth

Tags: ruby, httparty

Can anyone provide an example of using HTTParty using digest auth? I can't find examples on the net and was hoping someone could provide some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can set the username and password using the `digest_auth` method when defining your class

```
class Foo
  include HTTParty
  digest_auth 'username', 'password'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Rob's answer worked for me, but there's another way that doesn't affect the entire class. You could thus change the values for each call.

The following is slightly modified from the [HTTParty doc](http://johnnunemaker.com/httparty/):

```
class Twitter
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'twitter.com'

  def initialize(u, p)
    @auth = {:username => u, :password => p}
  end

  def post(text)
    options = { :body => {:status => text}, :digest_auth => @auth }
    self.class.post('/statuses/update.json', options)
  end
end
```

See the `digest_auth` part? I changed that from the original example's `basic_auth`.

Comment: this isn't working for me. trying with monero-rpc-client